# Matplotlib add_subplot & change_geometry bug?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am building a PyQt4 GUI with embedded Matplotlib (1.4.3).  It lets a user select from a list of available parameters to plot & gives them control to add/remove, rescale subplots etc. to send their data to.  Anyway, I came across this behavior of `add_subplot` followed by `change_geometry` that I didn't expect.

Make a subplot in the 2,1,2 position:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(0, 10, 0.1)
y1 = 0.05 * x**2
y2 = -1 *y1
figure = plt.figure()
ax1 = figure.add_subplot(2,1,2,label='sub2')
ax1.plot(x, y1, 'g-')
plt.show()
```

That was a mistake lets change it to subplot #1 and relabel

```
ax1.change_geometry(2,1,1)
ax1.set_label('sub1')
```

Ok, Now lets add subplot 2 for real this time...

```
ax2 = figure.add_subplot(2,1,2,label='sub2')
ax2.plot(x, y2, 'b-')
plt.draw()
```

[image] Wait a minute it plotted on Subplot 1 ... and where is my subplot 2?  Lets look at ax1, and ax2

```
ax1
<matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at 0xcaa32b0>
ax2
<matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at 0xcaa32b0>
```

They are the same axes?  So after some digging I came across [This GitHub Issue 429](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/429) and it says it is fixed ... but it doesn't look like it to me.  Am I missing something or is this really still an issue?

Comment: What version of matplotlib are you using?  Your example works fine for me in 1.4.3

Comment: As stated above I am using 1.4.3.  So at the end you have 2 separate subplots?  I have tired it on 2 different machines (one with 1.4.3 and one with 1.4.2) both in an Ipython console & regular Python3 (using anaconda) and I get the results shown in the picture above ... strange.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I just missed the version in the question.  Yes, I get two separate subplots when I try it.  Hmm.  Are you doing it interactively or in a script?

Comment: Ok, well, you are right, this is strange.  When I put the whole code into a single cell I duplicate your results.  When I first tried it I just typed things into ipython one line at a time and it worked fine. Hmmm....

Comment: My original issue was in a PyQT4 GUI application were the user can manipulate/move/add subplots.  Occasionally with the right steps of add/remove etc. I would get a line plotted on the wrong axes and a missing subplot.  The full application was to long to post here so I cut it down to a small example to demonstrate the issue.  The only real difference in my PyQT app is that I don't use `matplotlib.pyplot` instead I import `Figure` and `FigureCanvasQTAgg` ... but the behavior is the same either way.

Comment: In that case it may be that the issue you found was not, apparently, quite fixed all the way.  You may want to go ahead and post there to reopen it, this is a nice, short, reproducible example.

Comment: I create an issue on Github.  It was confirmed and added to the next point release milestone within a few minutes of posting.  I am new to Python & Matplotlib but very impressed by the responsiveness.  https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/4786

Comment: Good diagnosis and bug report! Could I recommend that you copy the above into a self answer and accept so that the question shows as answered and is useful for future viewers who find it?

Comment: I added the answer but it wont let me accept it as an answer yet.  There seems to be a waiting period on accepting your own answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I create this as an issue on Github. It was confirmed and added to the next point release milestone.

[GitHub Issue 4786](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/4786)